# Tabela preenchida por outras tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso criar uma tabela com PHP e MySQL que é preenchida por outras tabelas, todas tabelas tem uma coluna centro_custo, também fiz uma coluna código, para cada centro_custo porém não estou sabendo como implementa-la.

> `codigo`,`periodo`, `empresa`, `centro_custo`, `valor`
>   EX: ('100','2017-12-31','RJ','ADM.SERVICOS', '5166.87'),

Com os valores de 3 tabelas parecidas como o insert acima, preciso preencher uma outra, que devera ficar parecido com isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver na imagem nem toda tabela tem todos centros de custo, testando este SELECT:

```
SELECT b.centro_custo, SUM(a.valor), SUM(b.inss + b.fgts), SUM(c.comissao + c.meta + c.extra)
FROM informatica_salario_bruto a, informatica_tributos b, informatica_variavel c
WHERE b.centro_custo = a.centro_custo
AND b.centro_custo = c.centro_custo
AND b.periodo = "2017-12-31"
AND b.periodo = a.periodo
AND b.periodo = c.periodo
GROUP BY b.centro_custo;
```

Não retorna todos centro_custo de B, apenas os que são comuns entre as 3 tabelas e os valores saem multiplicados, parece que o SQL cria o mesmo centro de custo varias vezes EX:

```
ADM       ADM
ADM       PRODUCAO
ADM       ENGENHARIA
COMERCIAL ADM
COMERCIAL PRODUCAO
COMERCIAL ENGENHARIA
```

Criando o mesmo valor varias vezes e assim saindo os valores errados, o SUM também parece confundir, somando os valores com mesmo centro_custo de tabelas diferentes.

Edição: Outro problema que encontro é que quando vou imprimir o dados em PHP o query é guardado em um vetor ou seja, os dados saem em sequencia, então no exemplo da imagem o VALOR 1º TABELA salta a linha do meio, pois esse centro_custo não tem valor, como é possível fazer isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que estou entendendo sobre o que quer fazer pelo exemplo acima, o modo seria é o seguinte:

```
SELECT 
    B.CENTRO_CUSTO, SUM(A.VALOR), SUM(B.INSS + B.FGTS), SUM(C.COMISSAO + C.META + C.EXTRA)
FROM 
    INFORMATICA_SALARIO_BRUTO A
INNER JOIN 
    INFORMATICA_TRIBUTOS B ON B.CENTRO_CUSTO = A.CENTRO_CUSTO AND B.PERIODO = A.PERIODO
INNER JOIN 
    INFORMATICA_VARIAVEL C ON C.CENTRO_CUSTO = B.CENTRO_CUSTO AND C.PERIODO = B.PERIODO
WHERE  
    B.PERIODO = '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY
    B.CENTRO_CUSTO
```

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado pela resposta. Conferi a sua sugestão e ocorreu um problema, os valores ficam errados. Alguns saem multiplicados por 3 outros saem certos, já outros multiplicados por 10. Acredito que seja o problema que citei, os centros de custo se multiplicam. O centro de custo B, tem uma coluna que as outras não possuem e ela não foi "impressa" também.

Comment: Você tem um exemplo prático pra apresentar? Com os valores em cada tabela e qual o valor esperado na resposta?

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema criando 3 tabelas temporárias, assim não é necessário fazer o SUM com mais de uma tabela no SELECT, já pego os valor somados.

Comment: Entendo, talvez não fosse nem necessário criar essas temporárias, mas se quiser manter assim tudo bem. Se a resposta ajudou de alguma forma dá um ponto positivo pra ela.

Answer (score 1):

Para inserir dados de uma ou várias colunas numa nova tabela podemos utilizar um `INSERT INTO` combinado com um `SELECT` ou a syntax `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`

Exemplos:

```
INSERT INTO tabela_a (coluna1, coluna2) SELECT coluna1,coluna2 FROM tabela_b INNER JOIN tabela_c ON tabela_b.id = tabela_c.id;

CREATE TABLE tabela_copia [AS] SELECT * FROM tabela_orininal;
```